# Strict standards: Only variables should be passed by reference while echoing something

Tags: php, standards, strict

Hello i'm trying to get file name from other file name's parts...
it'll return me desire ans but also show Error.
my code is like that.

```
$fileName = 'somemovieoraudiooranyfiles.mp4';
echo __DIR__ . "/video_views/" . substr($fileName, 0,-strlen(end(explode('.', $fileName)))) . "txt";
```

Comment: `pathinfo()` or `basename()` might be a better approach for what you try to do there...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the manual entry for `end()`.  It takes a variable as a reference.  The return of the `explode()` call is not a variable and can't be referenced.

You get the desired result because `end()` does two things:

1. Moves the array pointer to the end of the array (it is unable to move the pointer in the original array because there is no array variable to reference)
2. Returns the last element of the array (this it is doing)

http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php

> The array. This array is passed by reference because it is modified by
>   the function. This means you must pass it a real variable and not a
>   function returning an array because only actual variables may be
>   passed by reference.

To get just the filename with no extension use `pathinfo()`:

```
echo __DIR__ . '/video_views/' . pathinfo($fileName, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '.txt';
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP do not put so many functions altogether at the same time. Split them in to steps. Here end is taking var as reference. write it like this;

```
$parts = explode('.', $fileName);
$ext = end($parts);
$f = substr($fileName, 0,-strlen($ext));
echo DIR . "/video_views/" . $f . "txt";
```

What you are trying to do can be easily done with PHP's pathinfo
http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php